# Unable to use Swiper.js v11 with VUE.JS v3 : dependency was not found

Tags: vue.js, npm, package.json, swiper.js

I'm working on a vue.js V3.0.0 project, and would like to use swiper.js.

As long as I'm trying to import swiper package with "sub-folder" package (`import Swiper from 'swiper/element/bundle';` for instance) I have the message :

```
This dependency was not found:

To install it, you can run: npm install --save swiper/element/bundle
```

My package.json looks like that :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "firebase": "^9.6.2",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.1",
    "swiper": "^11.0.3",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-pdf-embed": "^1.1.1",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.12",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.2.17",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.8",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "postcss": "^7.0.39",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.17"
  }
```

Do you have any clue of what's wrong with it ?

Thank you so much ! I'm struggling with that...

Comment: Have you tried importing from `"swiper"` directly? Maybe the file you're trying to import just doesn't exist

Comment: It's specific to your setup, it potentially doesn't support lib's "exports" entry https://unpkg.com/browse/swiper@11.0.3/package.json which is responsible for swiper/element/bundle virtual import path . Try to import the real module, e.g. swiper/swiper-element-bundle.mjs or swiper/swiper-element-bundle.js

Comment: Yes, I think it's because swiper has a `"type": "module",` in his package.json. Do you know how can I add module support in my project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution without rebuilding my project with a new version of vue.js : using an old swiper version which is not an ESM module : swiper@6.

Thank you for your time !